# ASN.1 SubType Constraint Resolution

Tags: asn.1

ASN.1 allows you to declare "sub-types", which basically impose additional constraints on regular types.

So, a regular type would be:

```
IntType ::= INTEGER
```

But you could constrain the type, by creating a "subtype" that only allows values within a certain range, such as:

```
IntType ::= INTEGER (1..100)
```

This declares `IntType` as an `INTEGER` that must fall between 1 and 100.

My question is, once a Sub-Type is declared, how does ASN.1 handle further constraints on the sub type?  Suppose I also say:

```
AnotherIntType ::= IntType (1..50)
```

Is that valid?  I've now created a second SubType which further constrains `IntType`.  But what if the constraints contradict each other, as in:

```
AnotherIntType ::= IntType (1..200)
```

Are there specific rules for resolving these contradictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the standard

> 47.4.2 A "ValueRange" specifies the values in a range of values which are designated by specifying the values of the
>   endpoints of the range. This notation can only be applied to integer types, the "PermittedAlphabet" of certain restricted
>   character string types (IA5String, NumericString, PrintableString, VisibleString, BMPString,
>   UniversalString and UTF8String only) and real types. All values specified in the "ValueRange" are required to be
>   in the root of the parent type.

Your first example

```
AnotherIntType ::= IntType (1..50)
```

is valid. Allowed values are the integers from 1 to 50.

The second example

```
AnotherIntType ::= IntType (1..200)
```

is not valid since not all values in the value range are in the parent type. `IntType` contains only the integers from 1 to 100.